# Pass input parameters to returned JS functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass input parameters from one function to another function inside a return statement. However in below example input1 and input2 are undefined. The values inside the return statement are undefined while inside the factory function they are not. How do I pass the values into the returned func()?

```
   function func(input1,input2) {
     console.log(input1,input2)
     // "undefined, undefined"
   }
    
    angular.module("factory").factory("test", (input1, input2) => {
     console.log(input1, input2)
     //"input1", "input2"
        return {
            func: (input1, input2) => {
                func(input1, input2);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: The `func()`  *method* you return takes its own `input1` and `input2` which shadow the `input1` and `input2` from the parent function. If you don't need parameters for the methods, just remove them and the `func` function will use the outer ones.

Comment: The input1 in your `func :` function is not the same as outside it. It is a local param. You can omit input1,and input2 from the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
func: (input1, input2) => {
```

*shadows* the parameter of the outer function (by declaring it's own parameters with the same names). So just remove those. E.g.

```
angular.module("factory").factory("test", (input1, input2) => {
    return {
        func: () => {
            func(input1, input2);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The input1 and input2 in `func :` function are not the same as outside it. They are local params which will be passed on function call. You can omit input1 and input2 from the definition and call the function like this `func()`.

```
console.log(input1, input2)
     //"input1", "input2"
        return {
            func: () => {        
               func(input1, input2);
            }
        };
```